# got error on import excel to existing table in access by vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

i want upload An Excel File to Existing Table ("boors") in Access

but i want Import only Odd Columns (Skip Even Columns)

my code is:

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "boors", fileName, True
End Sub
```

my upload button code:
>of course i want get Only Odd Column of "temp_table" no All(*)

```
Call ImportExcelSpreadsheet("txtpath.value", "temp_table")
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO boors SELECT * FROM temp_table"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "temp_table"
```

i got error:
 Field 'F2' dosen't exist in des table "boors"

Comment: In your sub `ImportExcelSpreadsheet` you are importing to a table called "Sample" and not using the table name that is passed to the procedure. Rather than importing the Excel sheet only to delete it, consider linking to the sheet, as this won't cause database "bloat".

Comment: yes , change Sample to boors<br> but now got Field 'F2' dosen't exist in des table "boors"

Comment: This means that Access has "named" the fields in the imported Excel data, such as "F2", and this field doesn't exist in the table that you are inserting it into.

Comment: so why error is not on F1?

Comment: Is there a "F1" in the imported table?

Comment: no there is not

Comment: my even column are empty,  i delete it on excel file worked correctly ,  i think if specific range of odd column like this it will work: DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "t1", fileName, True, "a:a,c:c,e:e"   but it got error

Comment: What are the fields in the two tables?

Comment: that fields on both is same on  Name and Number of field

Comment: TransferspreadSheet can only import continuous range. Why do you have alternate empty columns in sheet? Of course there are no matching fields for these empty columns. Why is Excel involved - why is data even in Excel?

Comment: my excel is exported by other system that include empty column on even